# I can't trigger SageMaker TrainJob from ECS; getting this exception: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to trigger a Sagemaker Trainjob from my flask app, which will be hosted on ECS Fargate.

When I run the same script in separate Python script it runs fine, but when I'm trying to do the same in Flask script, it gives the above mentioned exception. Below is a snippet of the code!

```
role = 'AmazonSageMaker-ExecutioRole-20221019T223514'
estimator = Estimator(role=role,
                      instance=1,
                      instance_type='ml.g4dn.xlarge'
                      image_uri=img,
                      hyperparameters=parms)
estimator.fit()
```

The exception occurs at `estimator.fit()`

Any help would be appreciated!

I have added the respective policies of ECS and Sagemaker to the role, but still no luck!

Comment: "I have added the respective policies of ECS and Sagemaker to the role" The ECS Task role, or the ECS execution role? You have to add a Task role to your ECS Task (which is optional, so you may not even have one currently) with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: A have added `ecsTaskExecutionRole` to my ECS task! Is that what you are pointing to?

Comment: No, there is a Task Role, and a Task Execution Role. The Task Execution Role is used by ECS to access things like ECR and Secrets Manager when starting your task. The Task Role is used by any software running inside your container. You need to have a Task Role with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks Mark, It really helped! I added the Task Role with all required policies and it worked!